# Maybe, Is it a disadvantage of Gradient Descent?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

## What is a disadvantage of Gradient Descent?

I'm trying to code a Linear Regression model.

```
# My example data, X is the height and y is the weight.
X = np.array([[147, 150, 153, 158, 163, 165, 168, 170, 173, 175, 178, 180, 183]]).T
y = np.array([[49, 50, 51,  54, 58, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68]]).T
# Visualize data 
plt.plot(X, y, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('Height (cm)')
plt.ylabel('Weight (kg)')
plt.show()
```

Data visualize

[image]

The first method. I compute Loss function:

[image]

And solution:

[image]

```
one = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
Xbar = np.concatenate((one, X), axis = 1)

A = np.dot(Xbar.T, Xbar)
b = np.dot(Xbar.T, y)

w = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A), b)
```

And results
I found weight w = 0.55920496 and b = -33.73541021

### The seconds method. I use sklearn package:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.intercept_)
print(clf.coef_[0])
```

I found weight w = 0.55920496 and b = -33.73541021

### But when I use Gradient Descent method

Weight is updated as the below

```
w = w -(1/m)*learning_rate*( X.T.dot((prediction - y)))
```

(bias is added in w matrix) 
And result:
weight and Loss is exploded. They are too large. But I tried to normalize X and y

```
X = (X - np.mean(X))/np.var(X)
y = (y-np.mean(y))/np.var(y)
```

[image]
And the result of the three methods is the same.

## Can you tell me the reason? And how to sklearn.linear model find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first and second solution you are using the exact solution formula which produces the most perfect solution for linear regression. There is no such formulas for other models that's why we are using gradient descent which is an iterative algorithm to solve the problem. If the learning rate is too high the algorithm will diverge. With the suitable learning rate hopefully it will converge to the exact solution. [learning rate effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k66f3.png)

Comment: Thank you. Before I normalize X and y. Loss and weight value is exploded and that goes to infinity. Although, I changed learning rate is small.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding. I think you are saying that you changed learning rate to smaller value and it's still diverging, yes?

Comment: Yes. I changed learning rate to a smaller value and it's still diverging

Comment: The only hyper parameter in gradient descent formula is the learning rate. You need to set it to the correct value. In your case it may not being small enough. sometimes it needs to be too small for example 0.000001 (I experienced such small values in some problems)